# Is transferring JSON data in Django possible without JS / JQuery?

Tags: python, html, django

I am learning how to handle JSON files in Django and I have successfully unpacked JSON, but now I would like to put it inside the table.

Is there a way to do that with pure HTML and using so called "tornado brackets" {{ }} not with jQuery / JS functions?

My code:

API BACKEND FILE

```
from requests import get


default_values = {
    "repoName": "",
    "repoURL": ""
    }

def get_response():
    response = get_json()

    main_dictionary = {
        "items":[]
    }

    try:
        for repos in response:
            main_dictionary["items"].append({
                "repoName": repos["name"],
                "repoURL": repos["html_url"]
                })

    except KeyError as error:
        print("Key Error, check the validity of the keys you try to use to decode JSON")

    return main_dictionary["items"]


def get_json():
    first_response = get('https://api.github.com/users/jacobtoye/repos')

    response = first_response.json()

    return response
```

A FAILED ATTEMPT AT RENDERING PURE HTML TABLE

```
{% block content %}

<table>
    <tr>
{% for repos in response %}
        <td>{{ repoName }}</td>
    {% if not forloop.last and forloop.counter == 3 or forloop.counter == 6 %}
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
    <tr>
{% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```

The table doesn't show at all.
I don't think that any other code files are substantial for this problem, but if you think you need more code, LMK I will gladly show you :)

Comment: You will need JSON.parse() to use the JSON response in the frontend and for that, you would javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django's views you usually pass such values as `context`.

function based view:

```
def a_view(request):
    context = {
        'some_things': Thing.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

class based view:

```
class TheView(View):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['some_things'] = Thing.objects.all()
        return context
```

With any of given approaches in template it will work like this:

```
{% for thing in some_things %}
    {{ thing }}, {{ thing.id }}, {{ thing.get_related_things }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You're an awesome person @NixonSparrow. Thank you.
You helped me figure it out and not did it for me. There is a special place in heaven for people like you :)

Comment: I just had similar problems and sometimes can relate ;)

Comment: Still thanks for not doing this for me, but helping me grow <3