# Adding table data element identifier in JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to create an edit button for each data cell in the column and I saw in this tutorial that to start things of I need to add an identifier to the Table Data Cell element (  ): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNxWUfw1J_w, but I have those tds defined in JS:

```js
function refresh_row(row, values) {
  var tds = $(row).children('td');
  var ii = 0;

  $(tds[ii]).html(values.type.name);
  ii++;
  $(tds[ii]).html(values.description);
  ii++;
  $(tds[ii]).html(values.company);
  ii++;
  $(tds[ii]).html(values.place);
  ii++;
}
```

Is there any way to add an identifier like:

```js
id="result-${obj.id}" data-testid="${obj.id}""
```

to the `values.description` data cell elements?

If it makes it any easier, `values` is a Python dictionary populated with JSON data similar to the one used in this question: [Is transferring JSON data in Django possible without JS / JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72593154/is-transferring-json-data-in-django-possible-without-js-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `attr('id'...)` and `data('testid'...)` to achieve this:

```js
  $(tds[ii]).html(values.description).attr('id', 'result-${obj.id}').data('testid', '${obj.id}')
```